# Scraping Webpage Tables Data Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have created a script that scrapes data from table of a website and copies the same to a excel sheet. Basically it does the following

1. Goes to the link,
2. fill up a textbox and selects a value from a dropdown press a button,
3. Fetches the data.
   The first two part is working perfectly however the data scraping is not working. Below is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Delete
 'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = "Symbol"
 'Cells(3, 1).Font.Bold = True
Dim i As Long, strText As String

Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object, hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object
 Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, Tr As Object, Td As Object

Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

'Shell "RunDll32.exe Inetcpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 11"

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
 Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not ie.busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With
' Input the userid and password
    'ie.document.getElementById("symbol").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    ie.document.getElementById("symbol").Value = TextBox1.Text
    ie.document.getElementById("dateRange").selectedIndex = "4"
    ie.document.getElementById("get").Click
    

While ie.busy
 DoEvents
 Wend


 
 Set doc = ie.document
 Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")


 y = 2 'Column B in Excel
 z = 3 'Row 3 in Excel
 For Each tb In hTable
 Set hHead = tb.getElementsByTagName("th")
 For Each hh In hHead
 Set hTR = hh.getElementsByTagName("tr")
 For Each Tr In hTR


 Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("th")
 y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
 For Each th In hTD
 ws.Cells(z, y).Value = th.innerText
 y = y + 1
 Next th
 DoEvents
 z = z + 1
 Next Tr
 Exit For
 Next hh
 Exit For

 Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
 For Each bb In hBody

 Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
 For Each Tr In hTR


 Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
 y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
 For Each Td In hTD
 ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Td.innerText
 y = y + 1
 Next Td
 DoEvents
 z = z + 1
 Next Tr
 Exit For
 Next bb
 z = z + 1
 Exit For
 Next tb
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me please..!!

Comment: "Not working" is not really a helpful description... can you be more specific?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. What is textbox1.value here >> ie.document.getElementById("symbol").Value = TextBox1.Text

Comment: Textbox1 value is a textbox in excel form from which the value is entered to the website textbox. It can be replaced with "BAJFINANCE"

Comment: And what isn't working? Your second wait isn't a proper wait by the way. Use the same wait format as you used the first time and then check whether longer wait times help with obtaining a result if that is the unspecified problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use F12 developer tools to check the Table HTML elements, we can see that there only have one `<table>` tag and one `<tbody>` element, in the tbody, the first row is the header row, others are the data row. In the header row, we can see that the `<th>` elements don't contain the `<tr>` tag

[image]

> ```
>  Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
>  
>  y = 2 'Column B in Excel
>  z = 3 'Row 3 in Excel
>  For Each tb In hTable
>  Set hHead = tb.getElementsByTagName("th")
>  For Each hh In hHead
>  Set hTR = hh.getElementsByTagName("tr")
>  For Each Tr In hTR
> ```

So, if we using the above code, after finding the `<th>` elements, it will not go deep to loop through the table.

Try to refer the following code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object
 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim i As Long, strText As String

    'Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object, hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object
    'Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, tr As Object, Td As Object

    Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

    'Shell "RunDll32.exe Inetcpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 11"

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 800
        .Width = 800

    Do Until Not IE.busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With
    ' Input the userid and password
    'ie.document.getElementById("symbol").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    IE.document.getElementById("symbol").Value = "BAJFINANCE"
    IE.document.getElementById("dateRange").selectedIndex = "4"
    IE.document.getElementById("get").Click
    

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
 
    Set doc = IE.document
     
    y = 2
    z = 3
    
    Dim table As Object, tbody As Object, datarow As Object, thlist As Object, trlist As Object
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    
    'find the tbody. Since it only conatin one table and tbody
    Set tbody = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
    'find tha theader
    Set thlist = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("th")
     
    'Debug.Print thlist.Length
    
    'loop through the header column and capture the value.
    Dim ii As Integer
    For ii = 0 To thlist.Length - 1
        ws.Cells(z, y).Value = thlist(ii).innerText
        y = y + 1
    Next ii
    
    'get all data row
    Set datarow = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
    'init the data row index and column index.
    y = 2
    z = 4
    
    'loop through the data row and get all td. and then capture the value.
    Dim jj As Integer
    Dim datarowtdlist As Object
    
    For jj = 1 To datarow.Length - 1
        Set datarowtdlist = datarow(jj).getElementsByTagName("td")
        
        'the x variable is used to set the column index.
        Dim hh As Integer, x As Integer
        x = y
        For hh = 0 To datarowtdlist.Length - 1
            ws.Cells(z, x).Value = datarowtdlist(hh).innerText
            x = x + 1
        Next hh
        z = z + 1
    Next jj
     
    Set IE = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]